# How to get data from script and display in php form (dialog box)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a requirement where

```
<div class="button" id="room_open" value="<?php echo $Records['room_id'];?>" onclick="tappedOnRoom(<?php echo $Records['room_id'].","."'".$Records['room_status']."'".","."'".$Records['block_num']."'";?>)"><?php echo $Records['block_num']."-".$Records['room_id'];?></div>
```

And my script is:

```
function tappedOnRoom(id,status,block){                     
if(status == 'Open')            
   {                
      $(function() {
         $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ title: "Book a Room",width: 835, height:300});
       });
    }
}
```

So, when my div is clicked, the script checks the `status` and if the `status` is "**Open**", then a form opens in a dialog box. So, my requirement is that I need to display `block_num` and `room_id` in the form dynamically.

My form contains:

```
<output type="text" id="blockNum" name="blockNum" class="span6" value=""/>
<output type="text" id="roomNum" name="roomNum" class="span6" value=""/>
```

Now, I would like to display `block` and `status` in the above output types.

Comment: <div> tag don't have attribute value

Comment: You mean, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/2u7SQ/

Comment: have you tried `val()` method? Assuming `output` tags are actually `input` tags with a typo

Comment: Apart from the problem. I think `output` is not self closing tag. [An `output` element must have both a start tag and an end tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/output.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're passing it to a function. So this would be fairly easy using JQuery.

In your `tappedOnRoom` function:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ title: "Book a Room",width: 835, height:300});
    $("#blockNum").val(block);
    $("#roomNum").val(status);
}
```

You may also want to look at [this example](http://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/uidialog/) for a different way to write it.

**Edit**

I would advise you to not use the output tag. To be honest it is not a tag I have used and the examples I have seen, make it seem like they are really designed for simple calculations. Furthermore they are not supported by Internet Explorer. While most people don't use IE anymore, and developers tend to have a wide variety of angry epithets at the ready when the browser is mentioned, the fact is that you are still making your application unusable for a large number of people.

SO, instead I would advise you to use a `<span>` or `<div>` tag which works on all browsers, and which Jquery can insert into quite easily, Simply replace your output tags with something like this:

```
<div id="blockNum" name="blockNum" class="span6"> </div>
<div id="roomNum" name="roomNum" class="span6"> </div>
```

Then you can adapt the JQuery to something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ title: "Book a Room",width: 835, height:300});
    $("#blockNum").text(block);
    $("#roomNum").text(status);
}
```

Regarding your hiding of divs, this is primarily a CSS question, although you can use JQuery to actually program the CSS. It wasn't clear to me that you didn't actually have the dialog portion down as far as hiding. I did a quick search and found [this](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated) which looks like it does exactly what you want - just substitute the JQuery `#opener` for `#room_open`. It makes use of the `show` feature of `.dialog`.

P.S. in this example they use special effects. I believe you can use "appear" and "hide", and you can certainly just shorten the duration, to avoid any animations, if you wanted to.

Comment: This one worked good. But I have got couple of questions as well.
    <div id="dialog" title="">
       <div class="innerLR">/* Some Text */</div>
    </div>
I would want the "dialog", which is in <div> must be hidden when page loads and must open only when I click on the <div id="room_open"..></div>

And one one thing regarding my previous posted question, could you please let me know how to insert the values [$("#blockNum").val(block);$("#roomNum").val(id);] obtained from the script.